# Modeling for multiple category membership in R

Tags: r, regression

I have data frame that looks like this:
      my.df

```
 y     cat1     cat2     2cat
 1        a       NA        0
 2        b        a        1
 3        c       NA        0
 4        a        c        1
```

4 participants here. Each participant can be categorized by the categories "a","b","c". They can also fall into the two categories, indicated by 2cat variable and cat2.

If we want to consider the fixed effects of each category, and ignoring the possibility of a participant being in 2 categories or more, this is trivial.

```
model <- y ~ factor(cat1)
m1 <- lm(model, my.df)
```

This essentially creates dummy variables "a","b","c". If, however, I am interested in the effect of multiple membership, I need to create a new data frame:

```
y    a    b    c    2cat
1    1    0    0       0
2    1    1    0       1
3    0    0    1       0
4    1    0    1       1
```

And run the models

```
 model <- y ~ a + b + c
 m2 <- lm(model, my.df)
```

This is doable with dcast and all that to massage the factor variable into a matrix of dummy variables; I am wondering if there's a quick way to specify in a model that allows me to run the same regression but using the first data structure (i.e. without expanding the factor variables into dummy matrices)?

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but it seems like a bad idea to have a column name that starts with a number